# What words can I form with these characters?

Tags: python, search, cpu-word

I have a question, if I have a **list with 16 characters** and a **txt with words**, how can I know which of those words can be formed with those 16 characters?

**Important: (without repeating)**

for example: "smalu"

The word "small" cannot be formed, because an "L" is missing

```
f = open ("twl06.txt", "r")
wordlist = ("a", "b", "c", "a", "r", "h", "k", "c", "i", "p", "h", "t", "r", "h", "k", "c")


while (True):
     line = f.readline () #For example "small"
     line2 = list(line)
     if line2 in wordlist: #Check if the word in line can be created with the characters that Wordlist has


         print (line) #Print the word that can be created
         print ("index of elements:" How do I do this?) #Print the index (in wordlist) of each character found
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has all sorts of functions to help find combinations/products/permutations of list elements. Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and for more assistance we ask that you provide code for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempts

Comment: Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, like said, we are not a code-writing ot tutorial service, If you wanted to achieve this you could preform something like this:

```
wordlist = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "r", "h", "k", "c", "i", "p", "h", "t", "r", "h", "k", "c"]
words = open("twl06.txt", "r").read().split() #Get all words in a text file

for word in words: #Cycle through all words
  indexes = [] #Set indexes to be blank
  usedletters = [] #Set used letters to blank

  for letter in word: #Cycle through each letter in the words
    if letter in wordlist: #Check if litter is in the list of words
      indexes.append(wordlist.index(letter)) #Append the index of the letter to our list
      usedletters.append(letter)
      wordlist[wordlist.index(letter)] = 0 #Set curreent used letter to placeholder
  if len(indexes) == len(word): #Check if we found all the letters
    print(word) #print the word that was found
    print("index of elements:", indexes) #print the list of that words indexes
  else: #In case we didnt get all the letters
    for i in range(len(indexes)): #Cycle through all replaced indexes
      wordlist[indexes[i]] = usedletters[i] #Set them back to their original letters
```

Comment: thank you very much friend, I appreciate it :) My intention was not to ask someone to finish my code (since that way I will never learn) I just wanted a clue of which way to go, since there are always methods or tricks that (because it is new) I do not know. Right now I start with paper and pencil to study the code, see how it works and learn ^-^